# Angular 6, how to configure CSS settings to create a persisting background color on all components?

Tags: css, angular, angular6

I'm trying to **create a background color that will persist on all of the components in my Angular app**.

When I target html `background: blue` in the `styles.css` (global style sheet) this works if I change the encapsulation on the `app.component.ts` to `ViewEncapsulation.Native`, however it covers every component in the app. Meaning the color is on top of every other component.

**I just want to set a background color that that will be behind all components in the app and persist**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed with this. I do not know if is the best approach, try to put into the body tag in `index.html`:

```
<body class=".." style="background:#E8EBEE;">
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. I will wait a little bit to see if anyone has perhaps the right approach if this is indeed incorrect. But Ill mark this as the answer otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Style.css or Style.scss file and add this code:

   ```
     body { 
       background: #EEE //Your Background Color that will be shown between all components even if the component fails to load.
       }
   ```
2. Import Renderer2 as follow:

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from 
   '@angular/core';
   ```
3. And If you want to add a custom background when a component being use, you will have to go to your component.ts File and add this code to the constructor:

   ```
   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
   this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background', 
   '#FFF');
   }
   ```

That code will apply a background color to the body only when this component is loaded.

Comment: this sounds great, but body {background: } doesnt do anything when applied in style.css for the global stlying. Targeting html{background: } has an effect but only up to about half the screen, where the component I am working with starts it stops.